# Difference on bash and ash parentheses

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ash

I was trying to use a diff command for comparing directory listings which works fine in bash:

```
diff  <(cd alpha ; find . -type f) <(cd beta; find . -type f)
```

However, on the ash (embedded device where no other shell is available) I get

```
-ash: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

Is there any difference regarding reading input operator `<` or parentheses `(` `)`?

Comment: Yes. `ash` doesn't support process substitution which `bash` does. Which is what the `<(command)` syntax is.

Comment: Also, this isn't always going to work reliably, anyway. You've obviously been lucky that it has so far. `find` is not guaranteed to return the list of files in any particular order, and the order may change as files are added/deleted/modified/etc. You could resolve that by adding a `| sort` after each `find`, though, I guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't confuse the angle bracket in `<( … )` with the one in redirections like `cat < file`. In bash, `<( echo hi )` is effectively a file with the contents "hi" (at least for reading purposes). So you can do

```
$ cat < <( echo hi )
hi
```

You can also do

```
$ echo <( : )
/dev/fd/63
```

And the shell actually expands that process substitution to a filename.

[Process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) is a bash feature. It is not part of the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) and does not exist in shells like ash. [Redirection](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07), on the other hand, is POSIX.

Answer (score 3):

The `<(command)` syntax is [Process Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) and is not supported by the `ash` shell (and other limited/etc. shells).

Comment: What's the alternative in ash if you need process substitution? Like the ability to use `tee`?

Answer (score 0):

I find this the most compact and comprehensible solution:

```
#!/bin/sh
diff /dev/fd/3 3<<-EOF /dev/fd/4 4<<-EOF
$(sort file1)
EOF
$(sort file2)
EOF
```

ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/639752/137528